# Passport Authentication req.isAuthenticated is always false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, authentication, passport.js

my authentication system isn´t working as expected.

first of all i want to show you my node.js file

```
//Initialize Express Web Server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
var lusca = require('lusca');
var io = require("socket.io")(http);

//require needs
var api = express.Router();
var ejs  = require('ejs');
var expressValidator = require("express-validator");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

//Connect to MongoDB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var configDB = require('./config/database.js');
mongoose.connect(configDB.url);

//Resolving paths with nodejs
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/MP/")));

//cookie parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

//Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));

//Init Sessions
app.use(session({
    secret:'SOME_HIDDEN_TEXT',
    cookie:{httpOnly:true/*, secure: true*/},
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection, autoReconnect: true})
}));

//Init Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

//Security
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//app.use(lusca.csrf());
/*app.use(lusca.csp(
    {"policy":{
        "default-src":"'self'",
        "script-src":"'self' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/*'",
        "img-src":"'self' 'http://placehold.it/*'",
        "connect-src":"'self'",
        "font-src":"*",
        "style-src":"'self' 'unsafe-inline' *"
    }}
));*/
app.use(lusca.hsts({maxAge:31536000}));
app.use(lusca.xframe('SAMEORIGIN'));
app.use(lusca.p3p('ABCDEF'));
app.use(lusca.xssProtection(true));
app.use(lusca.nosniff());

//Init API
var User = require(path.join(__dirname+"/model/user"));
require("./MP/routes/api")(api);
app.use("/api", api);

/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept');
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
         res.send(200);
     } else {
         next();
     }
});*/

//Setting up listening port
var port = 3000;

io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("user connected");
});

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set("views", path.resolve(__dirname,"MP","view"));

//Render View for Angular

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.render("index.ejs");
    console.log(req.headers.origin);
});

http.listen(port,function(){
    console.log('SERVER LISTENING ON PORT: '+port);
});
```

Next my angular app

```
"use strict";

var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute","ui.router", "ngSanitize","ngResource"]);

app.config(["$stateProvider" , "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider" , function ($stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, loginService) {
    $stateProvider
        .state("login", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "partials/index.html",
            controller: "indexCtrl"
        })
        .state("register", {
            url:"/register",
            templateUrl: "partials/register.html",
            controller: "indexCtrl"
        })
        .state("home", {
            url: "/en/",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        })
        .state("home.news", {
            url: "",
            templateUrl: "partials/news.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        })
        .state("home.gamer", {
            url: "gamer/",
            templateUrl: "partials/gamer.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        })
        .state("home.search", {
            url: "search/",
            templateUrl: "partials/search.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        })
        .state("home.games",{
            url: "games/",
            templateUrl: "partials/games.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        })
        .state("home.verify", {
            url: "verify/",
            templateUrl: "partials/verify.html",
            resolve: {
                loggedIn: checkLogin
            }
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
}]);

function checkLogin(loginService){
    return loginService.loggedIn();
}
```

here is my loginService

```
"use strict";

app.factory("loginService",["Api", "$location", "$state", "$q", "$rootScope",  function (Api,$location,$state,$q,$rootScope) {
    return {
        login: function (user,scope) {
            Api.login.post(user, function(regRes){
                console.log(regRes.data);
                if(regRes.data.error){
                    scope.error = { error : regRes.data.error};
                }else if(regRes.data.success === 1){
                    $state.go("home.news");
                }
            });
        },
        loggedIn: function(){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            Api.login.get(function(user){
                if(user.data != "0"){
                    $rootScope.currentUser = user;
                    deferred.resolve();
                }else{
                    $rootScope.currentUser = null;
                    deferred.reject();
                    $state.go("login");
                }  
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Last but not least my api

```
'use strict';
var User = require("../../model/user");
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: "e", passwordField: "p"},function(email, password, done){
    var user = new User();
    user.findEmail(escape(email),function(err, user){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        if(!user){
            return done(null,false, {error: "Email or Password is wrong. Please try again."});
        }
        user.comparePw(escape(password),user.password,function(err, isMatched){
            if(!isMatched){
                return done(null,false, {error: "Email or Password is wrong. Please try again."});
            }else{
                return done(null,user);
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user,done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user,done){
    var user = new User();
    user.findUserById(user, function(err, user){
        done(err,user);
    });
});

module.exports = function(router){
    router.get("/user", function(req, res){
        var user = new User();
        user.getGamer(function(err,response){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }else{
                res.json(response);
            }
        });
    });
    router.post("/user/login", function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('local', {session: true},function(err, user, info) {
            console.log(user + " " + info + " " + err);
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return res.json({error: "Email or Password is wrong. Please try again."}); }
            if(user.confirm == 0){ return res.json({error: "Please confirm your email address and try again."})}
            console.log(req.user);
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                console.log(req.session.id);
                console.log(req.user); //req.user is defined
                console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); //req.isAuthenticated() is true
                if (err) { return next(err); }
                res.json({success: 1});
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    });
    router.get("/user/login", function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.isAuthenticated()); //returns false
        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user: "0"); //send object with data:"0";
    });
};
```

UPDATE: This is my API service

```
app.factory("Api", ["$resource", function($resource){
    return {
        gamer: $resource("/api/user/:id", {_id: "@id"},{
            "get": { 
                method: "GET",
                interceptor: {
                    response: function(response) {
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            },
            "post":{
                method: "POST",
                interceptor:{
                    response: function(response){
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
        }),
        login: $resource("/api/user/login", {},{
            "post":{
                method: "POST",
                interceptor:{
                    response: function(response){
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            },
            "get":{
                method: "GET",
                interceptor:{
                    response: function(response){
                        return response;
                    }
                }
            }
        })  
    }
}]);
```

All time i called the loggedIn function i got a response of an object with data:"0". I´ve no clue why the req.isAuthenticated() is always false while the login was successfully via passport. A session cookie called connect.sid is set properly and got the same value as the session cookie stored in mongoose database. If i console.log isAuthenticated right after the login, i get the response of true, else it is always false. I also tried to allow CORS but it didnt worked. I searched the whole day on google to find a solution for this. Someone can help me?

Greetings Chzn

Comment: When you call your API, are your putting the `withCredentials: true`? Otherwise, your AJAX requests won't be able to get the (httpOnly) cookies.

Comment: i updated my post. i think im not doing this :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found it out by myself. My biggest mistake was that i forgot to set the same secret key for the cookie parser as follows.

```
app.use(cookieParser("SAME_SECRET")); //i let this blank

app.use(session({
    secret:'SAME_SECRET',
    cookie:{httpOnly:true/*, secure: true*/},
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
    store: new MongoStore({mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection, autoReconnect: true})
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `withCredentials` param in your request.

```
...    
login: $resource("/api/user/login", {},{
                "post":{
                    method: "POST",
                    withCredentials: true,
                    interceptor:{
                        response: function(response){
                            return response;
                        }
                    }
                },
                "get":{
                    method: "GET",
                    withCredentials: true,
                    interceptor:{
                        response: function(response){
                            return response;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })   
...
```

See: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#section_5)

Let me know if it works!

Comment: still returning false :/